# How is the cut-off frequency is set relatively to the signal of interest in a simple RC filter?

Tags: passive-filter

My question is simple. If I have a signal of interest max 30Hz and below what cutoff frequency should the RC low pass filter be set to?
Similarly, if I have a signal of interest min 30Hz and above what cutoff frequency should the RC high pass filter be set to?

I don't think the answer is fc must be set to exactly 30Hz, thats why I asked. Is there a rule of thumb and logic behind setting fc versus max/min signal of interest?

Comment: That depends on what you want to filter away! You don't build filters for the fun of it, normally, so you should come up with a complete specification of what the filter must do.

Comment: A better question would be: how much should I attenuate signals above 30Hz, and the answer will rely completely upon you usage of the signal between 0 - 30Hz and sensitivity and extend of noisy (unwanted) signals higher than 30Hz.

Comment: Think about the frequency response first. For example, if the input frequency is equal to the cut-off frequency of filter *(assuming it's 1st order filter -- 3dB/decade)* then the output signal will have an amplitude of ~71% of the input level. Think and decide.

Comment: @RohatKılıç So for the low pass filter with max 30Hz interest(30Hz component should not be attenuated but 31 32 33.. can be) I would set fc=60Hz. Would that make sense?

Comment: @user134429 Yes, but remember that if the input signal has 35Hz or even 59Hz components then these components will be passed to the output, because cut-off frequency is 60Hz. If you want a strict, keen, sharp filter then the filter must be high order *(3rd, or even 4th, depends on the application -- Can be an active filter as well)*. I personally recommend a 1st order filter with a fc of 40Hz instead of 60Hz if the requirements are not that strict.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how much "tilt", how much variation in sideband energy your receiver will tolerate.

In AM, the sidebands are counter-rotating in phase; the vector summation produces only Amplitude variation; any slight imbalance results in slight phase modulation as well.

People often are concerned about AM--PM conversion. Any LowPassFilter (and ANY circuit is ultimately becomes LowPass at the higher frequencies) thus causes some AM to PM conversion.

Summary: if your "signal" is just a single tone, with no need to preserve sidebands (the modulation information), and the exact amplitude does not matter, you can set the F3dB for best SNR, or flattest amplitude, or best pulse response (Bessel). If you have a data-eye, where phase modulation contains TIMING OF EDGES and thus affects the data-eye opening, you need to run some simulations or some back-of-envelope harmonic-analysis and phaseshift impacts.

Comment: Is this the answer to a different question?

Comment: If the OP has "signal of interest" with modulation, then this answer is very relevant.

Comment: Not likely at 30 Hz. I didn't downvote btw.